# The coordinate matrix of x y z is known, and a three-dimensional space curve is drawn according to x, y, z. Now how to find the slope of each point

Tags: matrices

The coordinate matrix of x y z is known, and a three-dimensional space curve is drawn according to x, y, z. Now how to find the slope of each point。The specific x y z coordinates are as follows
x=[16.6604388065247
16.6606832173864
16.6607266351292
16.6605424175751
16.6600604626046
16.6595955496176
16.6612428860471
16.6634323822435
16.6615411941684
16.6589638601973]
y=[121.069863759802
121.473750388985
121.878623860885
122.282878779977
122.676941113792
123.049481493681
123.414472784624
123.778030208679
124.131433687658
124.478800249564]
z=[0
0.125000000000000
0.250000000000000
0.375000000000000
0.500000000000000
0.625000000000000
0.750000000000000
0.875000000000000
1
1.12500000000000]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.